# JNDI LDAP Pooled Connections

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, connection-pooling

My JNDI connection pooling doesn't seem to be working as expected. When I run my test I see that new connections are created each time. The connections succeed (as in I can query against Active Directory just fine) but they aren't pooling as I expect them to. Here are some important notes about my setup:

1. Connection is going over SSL (i.e., ldaps)
2. Using a custom socket factory
3. Authentication to AD is done via "simple" authentication
4. Using the default pool configuration values (for now)

Here is the relevant code:

**TestLdapsPooling.java**

```java
public class TestLdapsPooling {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // needed system properties
        System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol", "ssl");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug", "fine");

        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, host);

        // use ssl
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");

        // authentication info
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple"); 
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username); 
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password); 

        // custom socket factory
        env.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "ldap.TrustedSocketFactory");

        // Enable connection pooling
        env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "true");

        // Create the initial context
        InitialDirContext context =  new InitialDirContext(env);
        System.out.println("First context created");

        // Create a second context
        InitialDirContext context2 =  new InitialDirContext(env);
        System.out.println("Second context created");

        // close first context
        context.close();
        System.out.println("First context closed");

        // close second context
        context2.close();
        System.out.println("Second context closed");

        // Create a third context - I would expect this to use a connection from the pool
        InitialDirContext context3 =  new InitialDirContext(env);
        System.out.println("Third context created");

        // close third context
        context3.close();
        System.out.println("Third context closed");
    }
}
```

**TrustedSocketFactory.java**

```java
public class TrustedSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory implements Comparator<SocketFactory> {

    // all the methods required from SSLSocketFactory

    @Override
    public int compare(SocketFactory arg0, SocketFactory arg1) {
        // not really sure what this value should be 
        // is this causing the pooling issue?
        return 0;
    }

}
```

**Output**:

```
Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@3f0ee7cb[testdomain.com:636]
Use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@3f0ee7cb
First context created
Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@75bd9247[testdomain.com:636]
Use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@75bd9247
Second context created
Release com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@3f0ee7cb
First context closed
Release com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@75bd9247
Second context closed
Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@7d417077[testdomain.com:636]
Use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@7d417077
Third context created
Release com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@7d417077
Third context closed
```

I would expect the third context to have reused one of the first two connections but the output looks like it creates its own connection. What do I need to change in order for the connection to be reused instead of a new connection being created?

Comment: You will not beleve this, but it is a documented fact: enabling connection pool debugging disables the pool. NB You are using a custom socket factory why?

Comment: I saw a comment somewhere that said that but I couldn't believe it. Funny and sad that it is true. We are using a custom socket factory so that we can easily customize the trust store without impacting other Java services running on the machine or even in the same application. Not sure if that is the best way but if there is a better way to achieve that please let me know.

Comment: The solution to all truststore problems is to have the server use a CA-signed certificate.

Comment: Yeah, we do that but there are different CAs for different use cases. In other words, we don't put all the trusted certificates into one large trust store but rather break the trust stores up based on use case.

Comment: I believe I am mistaken, and that this is not documented, and that I found it in a comment in the source code years ago when facing the same issue. I have probably mentioned it on SO once or twice too. I don't see the point of different truststores. Either you trust the CA or you don't.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the source where you found it, if you still have that? As for the CA trust, we trust different CAs for different uses. The Active Directory TLS is managed by an internal PKI and we would not want an external CA (e.g., DigiCert) having control over that. On the other hand, our server also makes external REST calls to other services that do chain up to publicly trusted CAs, like DigiCert. You could argue that we should trust the external CAs to not issue certs for our internal purposes but we prefer to explicitly control what they can issue certs for.

Comment: Well the link is just to somewhere in the JDK source code for the LDAP JNDI provider, and it was about 10 years ago ...

Comment: Connection pool debugging does not disables the pool, as I notice in 2021. I suppose you have some unclosed ressources: all of the DirContext, searchResult's NamingEnumeration, attributes' NamingEnumeration and values' NamingEnumeration have to be closed, see https://www.avisi.nl/blog/2015/03/27/java-ldap-connection-pooling

Answer (score 0):

Based on the "*What Gets Pooled*" section of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/config.html it's probably the custom socket factory that is disabling pooling:

> There are a couple of environment properties that automatically
>   disqualify a Context instance from using a pooled connection. A
>   Context instance cannot use a pooled connection if it has its
>   "java.naming.ldap.factory.socket" property set to a custom socket
>   factory class (...)

Answer (score 0):

From the ClientId code, the factory needs to implement `Comparator<String>` not `Comparator<SocketFactory>`. Socket factory class name is passed to the comparator.